# .svg url to UIImage iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch

I am getting .svg urls from server. how can I convert NSData from .svg url and convert it into UIImage. I am getting url like "https://storage.googleapis.com/pgcdn/ca/svg/lock.svg" and I am using this code

```
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        dispatch_queue_t callerQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
        dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.test.svg", NULL);
        dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        });
```

This function gives image as nil value.

Comment: plz use this link: https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit

Answer (score 2):

You can't load `.svg` as `UIImage`, but you can load a `UIWebView` with `.svg` content since the iOS browser can render SVG.

Some of the threads worth while exploring could be:

1. [Thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610419/how-to-render-svg-images-in-iphone-without-uiwebview)
2. [Thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957282/how-can-i-load-vector-image-directly-with-iphone-sdk)
3. [Thread 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624070/how-to-render-all-kind-of-svg-files-in-iphone)

You can also explore third party framework [SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit).